# How to convert a 'day/month' string to date in python and compare it with an Odoo date field?

Tags: python, odoo

I have a `day/month` string, I want to convert that string to date object and compare the last day of that month to another date

***Example:***
For `08/2021` (august, 2021) I want to compare the last day of that month (31-08-2021) to another date (date field),

For `02/2020` I what to compare 29-02-2020 < another_date (date field)

For `02/2021` I what to compare 28-02-2020 < another_date (date field)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `calendar.monthrange` to find the last day in the month if you don't want to add dateutil.

```py
import calendar
from datetime import datetime

def get_last_day_date(year_month_str):
     date = datetime.strptime(year_month_str, "%m/%Y")
     last_day = calendar.monthrange(date.year, date.month)[1]
     return datetime(date.year, date.month, last_day)

get_last_day_date("08/2020")
# datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 31, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This examples shows you how to convert '02/2020' to a Python `datetime` and how to get the last day of that month. You can use it to compare the result to another `datetime`:

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

date = '02/2020'
last_day = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%Y') + relativedelta(day=31)
# last_day will be a datetime of the last day of the month which you can use to compare against another datetime
```

In this example, the result is `datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 29, 0, 0)` because 2020 was a leap year

Answer (score 0):

```
b='08/2021'
a=b.split('/')
import calendar
import datetime
z=(str(calendar.monthrange(int(a[1]),int(a[0]))[1])+'-'+b.replace('/','-'))
d=datetime.datetime.strptime(z,'%d-%m-%Y').date()

print(d)
n=datetime.date.today()
print(n)
n<d
```

Output:

```
2021-08-31
2021-01-28

True
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by just importing/using **`datetime`** library and here you can see how.

By passing string date into method.

```
import datetime

def convert_string_to_datetime(self, datetime_in_string):
    datetime_in_string = str(datetime_in_string)
    datetime_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    datetime_in_datetime_format = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime_in_string, datetime_format)
    return datetime_in_datetime_format

new_datetime_field = convert_string_to_datetime(datetime_in_string)
```

By modifying with in single line

```
import datetime

new_datetime_field = datetime.datetime.strptime(YOUR_DATETIME_IN_STRING, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

After converting into **`datetime`** now comparison is possible like.

```
if new_datetime_field > odoo_datetime_field:
   pass
```